# wifi support for Realtek [10ec:8821] on VivoPC VM62N-G050R

Tags: networking

I've got a VivoPC VM62N-G050R,
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1131163-REG/asus_vivopc_vm62n_g050r_mini_desktop.html
(link provided just for info, neither recommending nor dis-recommending this particular vendor). Wired/wireless both work under its pre-installed win8.1, which I've got dual-booting with linux slackware 14.1x64, installed uefi/gpt. It's a vanilla slackware 14.1x64, except upgraded to kernel 4.1.6 (in an attempt to solve the problem below).

Wired networking works fine (as does everything else, afaict), but wireless is no-go; in fact, box hangs (requiring a cold start) when I try to iwconfig it. The googling I've done suggests the box's wireless chipset, details below, just isn't supported (though someone suggested the kernel upgrade I mentioned above, but that didn't work for me). I'm posting here in one last effort, hoping somebody knows of a linux driver/module/whatever to get this working. Details of chipset...

lspci -nnk gives:

```
---wired controller (no problem)---
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:859e]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
---wireless (this is the problem)---
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8821]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85b4]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
        Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

And iw list gives lots of the usual output (which I'll provide if requested), suggesting it ought to work, but it doesn't (not for me, at least). Any suggestions??? Thanks, John.

As per Rui's comment below, I'm adding

iwconfig gives:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point:Not-Associated  Tx-Power=0 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lsmod gives lots; I think the relevant lines are (I'll be happy to post all 99 if requested)...

```
rtl8821ae             215045  0
btcoexist              40784  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                18724  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                56083  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
```

Comment: You would better show us the ouput of "sudo lsmod" and "sudo iwconfig"

Comment: Obviously the chipset is supported, in so much as you have wlan0 and the module installed. the wifi client  is not configured.

Comment: and if your try this? if it hangs, which command and any errors? https://ezzata.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/connecting-slackware-to-wpa2psk-wireless-network/

Comment: "sudo uname -r" please

Comment: Thanks, Rui. uname -r is 4.1.6 (I'd upgraded kernel from stock slackware 14.1) And thanks for https://ezzata.wordpress.com/2012/1/12/connecting-slackware-to-wpa2psk-wireless-network link. Slack wireless config is indeed a pain, but I've already got it working on a whitebox with an Asus Z87I-Deluxe mb, so I think (emphasize "think":) I know how to do it. And google comments that it's not supported are mostly with respect to ubuntu, so other people using other distros seem to have had similar problems. Anyway, I'm not ruling out anything (except flying saucer interference).

Comment: I also have a realtek in a ARM here, and it is a POS. Even after wasting countless hours to put it to work, it works so much better but it breaks occasionally - and what I done, changing the firmware and compiling shit is not for the faintest of heart. Cheap hardware with bugs, mostly in energy saving management. I would buy an atheros wifi PCIe? card, and switch it.

Comment: (ran out of chars) the command that ultimately hangs the box is
**dhcpcd -d -h p si8star -s 192.168.1.8  wlan0**  Of course, that's
just the last step. I'd have to post all the /etc/rc.d/rc.wireless
and .conf stuff, the /etc/wpa_supplicant.c onf stuff, etc.
But if you're saying the posted output pretty much guarantees it's
being recognized and properly supported, then I'll re-check my config
(for the (n+1)-th time:). I agree the wifi chipset certainly seems to
be recognized, but **properly** supported may be a question, judging
from my experience and similar google comments.

Comment: Thanks again, Rui. Okay, I'll consider getting a separate usb wifi (can't install a card in this micro-itx mb) if I can't coerce the mb's "pos-wifi" to do something useful.

Comment: I have the same problem with rtl8821ae in my Asus Vivo vc62b. The wireless would connect and disconnect repeatedly to the access point with Debian Jessie kernel 3.16 giving slow downloads. The kernel would freeze with PClinuxOS kernel 4.1 requiring a power off restart. I had to disable the WLAN in the Asus UEFI. I am now trying newer kernels to find a solution or else replacing the mini PCIe module. Google has a lot of problems shown for rtl8821ae linux.

Comment: @Agree Sorry to hear you're having the same bad experience (although misery does love company:). Like you, as mentioned above, I upgraded to kernel 4.1.6 (along with kernel modules and kernel firmware), without luck. So now I'm also hoping/waiting for some future kernel that supports it. But I didn't have to disable it, just not try to use it. Maybe take a look at your network startup scripts, and comment out (or whatever) any wlan stuff it's executing (i.e., trying to execute). The wireless still works fine when I boot the pre-installed win8.1, so it's presumably not a hardware problem.